# Openpyxl - copy worksheet with merged cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy worksheets (within the same workbook) that have merged cells and I'm getting an error. I have fairly long templates that I copy and then populate for different projects. My code works if I unmerge all the cells, but that messes up all the formatting. I could unmerge the cells, copy the sheet, and then remerge them. However, there are a ton of merged cells and I have several different templates that I have to use. I don't have any control over the templates. I'm using openpyxl 2.5.4.

Here's my code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(temp)
wb.save(filename = "test.xlsx")
pg = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = pg.copy_worksheet(pg["sheet1"])
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-41-a49f299a8c1f>", line 1, in <module>
    ws = pg.copy_worksheet(pg["sheet1"])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 394, in copy_worksheet
    cp.copy_worksheet()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\copier.py", line 43, in copy_worksheet
    self.target.merged_cells = copy(self.source.merged_cells)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 88, in copy
    return copier(x)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\cell_range.py", line 456, in __copy__
    n.ranges.append(copy(r))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 88, in copy
    return copier(x)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\cell_range.py", line 136, in __copy__
    title=self.title)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_col'
```

I've seen other questions about copying styles for merged cells, but this won't copy the sheet at all. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Brandon

Comment: Potential bugs should always be submitted to the openpyxl bug tracker.

Comment: I just opened an issue. https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1215/cant-copy-worksheet-with-merged-cells

Answer (score 0):

You Can Easily Monkey Patch It:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.merge import MergedCellRange

def clone(self):
    return self.__class__(self.ws, self.coord)

MergedCellRange.__copy__ = clone
```